# How to run the CosmosOS File System on real hardware

Tags: c#, visual-studio, operating-system, cosmos

When trying to run my OS (made on CosmosOS) ISO on VMware (On Windows) and Virtualbox (on Mac), it shows the following error:

[image: OS Kernel Error]

How can I fix this? I used the following commands to initialize the file system:

```
Sys.FileSystem.CosmosVFS fileSys = new Cosmos.System.FileSystem.CosmosVFS();

Sys.FileSystem.VFS.VFSManager.RegisterVFS(fileSys);
```

The second command is inside the `BeforeRun()` function, and the first is before.

I tried building my OS as an ISO image, but I got the Kernel error posted above. I also got the following errors when building the code (I don't know whether they affect the building, as the build say that it is completed successfully, but they might have an effect):

[image: VS Error 1]

[image: VS Error 2]

I also cannot find a way to format the drive (maybe that is the issue). Could someone please help me make the file system work on real hardware?